# How to delete Active Record object with a foreign key without using cascading deletes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have two models, `LaserSheet` and `Item`, that relate to each other with a `has_many` relationship:

```
class LaserSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :items
  ...
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :laser_sheets
  ...
end
```

Because they have a many-to-many relationship, I want to be able to delete an `Item` without deleting its associated `LaserSheets`, and similarly delete a `LaserSheet` without deleting its associated `Items`. However, when I attempt to delete one of the objects I get a Foreign Key error:

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "items" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_f7f551ebf9" on table "laser_sheets" DETAIL: Key (id)=(293) is still referenced from table "laser_sheets".
```

**EDIT:**

DB migrations adding refs between the two models:

```
class AddItemRefToLaserSheets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :laser_sheets, :item
  end
end

class AddLaserSheetRefToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :items, :laser_sheet
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `has_many` relationships, should these be `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: Yes, looks like `has_and_belongs_to_many` would be a much better fit.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [dependent options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent).  You may want something like:

```
class LaserSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :nullify
  ...

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :laser_sheets, dependent: :nullify
  ...
```